# preg_replace with callback not replacing?

Tags: php

I have this function to replace a text with an url to url link.
The callback is used to check if it has http or not in the link, if it has not, add http on it:

```
<?php

function toLink($titulo){
    $url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i'; 

    $titulo = preg_replace_callback($url, function($matches) {
        $url = $matches[0];
        if (!preg_match('/^https?:\/\//', $url)) {
            $url = 'http://'.$matches[0];
            $url = '<a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank" 
                       title="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
        }
    },$titulo);


    return $titulo;
}


echo toLink("hi from www.google.com");
```

The return value is `hi from` where is my link?

Comment: I haven't really looked at the regex, but shouldn't the callback return something?

Comment: `return $url` seems like a good bet to me :-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic where should I return the url? inside pregmatch?

Comment: inside the callback?

Comment: At the end of the callback (`function($matches) { ... }`), after you've created the URL you want, return it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php example inclusive

Comment: `preg_replace` replaces the match with a specific thing, but `preg_replace_callback` replaces it with the result of the callback, so the callback needs to have a result, or it replaces the match with nothing.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks, it works!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Don'tPanic if you put down your comments in an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @sal I really thought this must have been a duplicate, because it seems like such an easy mistake to make, but I haven't been able to find one. Your answer is fine, no need to add another one IMO, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback needs to return the string (or value) that should be inserted.
[This](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php) gives you more information.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the callback function must return a value, to make this fully work. To tie things together, you just need a `return $url` statement in the end of the callback, like this:

```
function toLink($titulo){
    $url = '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i'; 

    $titulo = preg_replace_callback($url, function($matches) {
        $url = $matches[0];
        if (!preg_match('/^https?:\/\//', $url)) {
            $url = 'http://'.$matches[0];
            $url = '<a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank" 
                       title="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
        }
        return $url;    // <---- return the $url
    },$titulo);


    return $titulo;
}


echo toLink("hi from www.google.com");
```

Check the result on https://eval.in/1079110